Delta compatibility problem with PySpark in Dataproc GKE env
I've created a dataproc cluster using GKE and a custom image with pyspark 3.5.0. but can't get it to work with delta
The custom image docker file is this:
FROM us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/cloud-dataproc/spark/dataproc_2.2:3.5-dataproc-18
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip3 install python-dateutil
RUN pip3 install google-cloud-storage

The command used to create the cluster is this
gcloud dataproc clusters gke create spark-testing-custom-image     --region=us-central1     --gke-cluster=dataproc-cluster             --spark-engine-version=latest     --staging-bucket=my-staging-bucket    --pools="name=dataproc-pool,roles=default"     --setup-workload-identity --project my-project --properties=spark:spark.kubernetes.container.image=gcr.io/my-project/dockerfile:latest

I'am trying to execute a simple script to transfer data from one bucket to another and save it as delta
def main():
    print("Getting spark session")
    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("DeltaTest")\
        .config('spark.sql.extensions', 'io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension')\
        .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")\
        .getOrCreate()

    # This function retrieves a spark dataframe. It's working fine
    df_table = get_data(spark, LANDING_PATH, 'ts_ms', last_date_value, 'json', True, True)

    (
            df
            .write
            .partitionBy("year", "month", "day", "hour")
            .format("delta")
            .mode("overwrite")
            .option("checkpointLocation", bucket + "checkpoint")
            .save(bucket)
    )


I'am uploading this python file to GCS and i'am trying to manually upload the job through the GCS console
In the properties section these are my confs:
spark.jars.packages    io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.2.0,io.delta:delta-contribs_2.12:2.2.0
spark.sql.extensions    io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension
spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog    org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog
spark.delta.logStore.gs.impl    io.delta.storage.GCSLogStore
I actually wanted to run delta-core_2.13:3.4.0 but its not available in the maven repository accessed by google https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/delta/
Anyways, the error i'am getting is this
  File "/tmp/spark-af0301a3-6609-46d2-b56a-339bc1ef2ca1/estoque-historico-landing-to-bronze.py", line 262, in write_bronze_table
    df
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 1463, in save
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 179, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o180.save.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileFormatWriter$Empty2Null

Anybody have any idea what could be wrong?
